# AWS Athena - Operation cannot be paginated: get_query_results

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use boto3 to run a query in AWS Athena. but I'm getting this error:

```
 Operation cannot be paginated: get_query_results
```

This is my code:

```
client = boto3.client(
    'athena',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    region_name='us-east-1'
)

query = """ 

    select 1;

"""
response = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString=query,
    # QueryExecutionContext={
    #     'Database': 'Test45'
    # },
    ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': 's3://dft-dwh-files/raw_data/google_analytics/dev-test/'
    }
 )


paginator = client.get_paginator('get_query_results')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    QueryExecutionId='string',
    PaginationConfig={
        'MaxItems': 123,
        'PageSize': 123,
        'StartingToken': 'bafe7afc-07b5-4622-9019-2e3c92853913'
    }
)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I am not familiar with these technologies, but this article, [Paginating AWS API Results using the Boto3 Python SDK](https://www.awsadvent.com/2016/12/21/paginating-aws-api-results-using-the-boto3-python-sdk/), mentions "Some Boto3 services [...] don’t provide paginators" which it further suggests "You can also ask the individual service client’s `can_paginate` method if it supports paginating," which could suggest "If you get an error like this, it’s time to roll up your sleeves and write your own paginator." Not sure if this is the case, but the article may explain more to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm posting the solution here in case anyone else comes across this question like I did... You have to send the QueryExecutionId from `response`.

```
query_id = response['QueryExecutionId']

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    QueryExecutionId=query_id,
    PaginationConfig={
        'MaxItems': 123,
        'PageSize': 123,
        'StartingToken': None
    }
)
```

Even still, if your query is going to take a while, you will need to implement a waiter function first and THEN paginate once you know the query has succeeded. I recommend checking the `State` value from the `get_query_execution` function.

Comment: Note that setting `MaxItems` will give you at most `123` rows even if they are more rows.